# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving this error and am unable to figure out why.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\insert.php on line 32

```
    $SELECT = "SELECT id FROM heroes WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1";
    $INSERT = "INSERT INTO heroes (id, name, title, bp, ticket, diamond) VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$title', '$bp', '$ticket', '$diamond')";

    //Prepare statement
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($SELECT);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

    if ($rnum==0){
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($INSERT);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $title, $bp, $ticket, $diamond);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "New hero inserted successfully, sir!";
    } else { 
        echo "There is already a hero with this name, sir!";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $connection->close();
```

Comment: There are many, many discussions of this here and elsewhere on the internet. What research have you done? [Edit] the question and show that the many answers out there do not apply to this case.

Comment: NULL should not be quoted. Also, if id is an auto increment number, just leave it out of your insert.

Comment: By convention PHP steers towards lower-case variable names, so `$select` and `$insert` here. As an additional note, you can avoid these throw-away single-use variables and instead just put the query directly into the function call. This avoids any potential confusion where you use the wrong one by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have any params to bind in your insert:

```
$INSERT = "INSERT INTO heroes (id, name, title, bp, ticket, diamond) VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$title', '$bp', '$ticket', '$diamond')";
```

Do this:

```
$INSERT = "INSERT INTO heroes (name, title, bp, ticket, diamond) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Then the values you bind replace the question marks.

Also note there is a very significant difference between `NULL` and `'NULL'` -- the latter is a string. If you have an auto-incrementing ID field, just leave it out of the insert and the database will fill it in for you.

Comment: can you `prepare($SELECT);` a variable like he's done on the 3rd line of code?

Comment: You can also use named params like :ticket.  I would have a look at this PDO reference article: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Dean They're using Mysqli instead of PDO, which does not have named params.

Comment: @Isaac Sure, `prepare()` takes a string argument. It could be a constant, a literal string, a variable that contains a string, a function that returns a string, or an object that implements `__toString()`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky didn't know that was possible. I use PDO mainly and then bind params, probably won't change how I code it as I'll still prepare the string argument but it's still interesting to know! thank you!